# Installing Erlang / RabbitMQ on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I would like to install RabbitMQ on my Windows 10 64-bit PC.

The RabbitMQ installer reports that it requires Erlang to be installed.

I downloaded the erlang installer (OTP 19.1 Windows 64-bit Binary File (101629312)) from http://www.erlang.org/downloads . When I run it, it displays a dialog that reports "Error opening file for writing: C:\Program Files\erl8.1\Install.exe" and gives me the option of "Abort", "Retry", and "Ignore".

(Surely this installer is supposed to place files in "C:\Program Files\" directory rather than read them?)

If I click "Ignore" in the dialog, the installer *appears* to be working, and I get a good few subsequent dialogs, in all of which, I click "Ignore".

After the Erlang installer has run, I attempt to install RabbitMQ installer again but it reports that it requires Erlang to be installed.

Can somebody please help me?

Am I wrong to expect a software installer to "just work"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope this [link](http://windowsreport.com/error-opening-file-for-writing/) can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run your installer "As Administrator" (right click on the executable).

Since it tries to write in your `ProgramFiles` folder, your regular user rights are not enough (which is actually a good thing since that means you do not live constantly with Admin rights).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no previous version installed
and Erlang Process is running , so you to stop it first then run the Application as Administrator